# How many 5-digit PINs are there where 2, 4, and 7 appear at least once each?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations

An access control system uses a PIN code consisting of 4 digits (0-9). I was able to learn that the correct PIN includes the digits 2, 4, and 7 at least once each, with my super spy tricks. Only 2, 4 and 7 appear to have been pressed.
I would like to know how many possible PINs match this constraint. How many 5-digit PINs are there where 2, 4, and 7 appear at least once each?

So I am assuming that it is a simple solution based on the book, $10^5 -10^3=99,000$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: "Only 2, 4 and 7..." suggests that no other digit appears in the PIN, so you have just those three choices for each digit. Use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @DanielMathias WOuld it be like this 3!x4x10=240 possibilities? Like this? Or did I misunderstand the formula?

Comment: No, it would be $3^5-??+??$

Comment: In your first sentence, you describe a PIN code with four digits.  In the question at the end of the paragraph, you ask about five-digit codes.

Answer (score 2):

The cases where one of those digits is missed are cases of five digits and nine options each so it's:$9^5$. The whole options of PIN code are $10^5$.

So the amount of options with those digits is:$10^5-3\times 9^5$

Because we're doing this for every digit

Comment: WHy 7 options though?